# What are the sample size confidence interval calculations for the Agresti-Coull and Wilson methods for finite populations?

Tags: confidence-interval, sample-size, sample, finite-population

There are formulations for the calculus of the sample size based on Agresti-Coull and Wilson confidence intervals for infinite population in some works (like Piegorsch - 2004). However,  I didn´t find papers that deal with sample size formulas for finite population. Anyone knows the Agresti-Coull and Wilson sample size formulas for finite population?